# ruby on rails how to escape html tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I actually solved this using regex but I want to know if there's an easier to get around it as I'm not confident in my regex if I covered all possible rules. My problem is that I want to put double quotes (") around a text and print it. The text has html tags when retrieved in the database.

let's say I'm working on this,

```
@text = `<p>my <strong>legs <em>wants</em>&nbsp;</strong>ex <strong>desire</strong> blood sleep</p>`
```

When I tried `<%= raw "\"#{@text.html_safe}\"" %>` in my view, I'm getting this as my output:

```
"
my legs wants ex desire blood sleep

"
```

When I did something like `<%= "\"#{@text.html_safe}\"" %>` the output is:

```
"<p>my <strong>legs <em>wants</em>&nbsp;</strong>ex <strong>desire</strong> blood sleep</p>"
```

Any ideas? All i wanted to print out was `"my legs wants ex desire blood sleep"` literally

**UPDATE**

using strip_tags was cool and I thought it got me nearer to the answer, but unfortunately strip_tags isn't working in my controller/regular ruby. I'm still researching.

Comment: If you're finding the need to use `strip_tags` in your controller then perhaps your code would be better suited in a helper.  Helper functions can be used and reused in the view code as needed.

Comment: I'd suggest editing the question so that it is clear that you are looking for a solution outside of the view.  Since you are currently using ERB in your question it makes strip_tags a more correct solution to the question than the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
require 'nokogiri'
doc = Nokogiri('<p>my <strong>legs <em>wants</em>&nbsp;</strong>ex <strong>desire</strong>     blood sleep</p>'.gsub('&nbsp;', ' '))

# use Nokogiri to get plain text

# output it
= "\"#{doc.text.squeeze}\""
```

Comment: Sorry but when I try to add the library to my controller.rb, this error appears `cannot load such file -- nokogiri`

Comment: edit you Gemfile, add - gem 'nokogiri'. then "bundle install"

Comment: Yup, already had it on my gemfile and already ran "bundle install". And I still receive those errors. This is really weird.

Comment: If it's in your gemfile you don't need to require, it will already be loaded.  But honestly, I'm not sure what you're looking to get from nokogiri that strip_tags and sanitize don't already give you.

Comment: I need the content so that I can run it against my google-search gem. But strip_tags and sanitize only works for me in views, and my search algorithm is in my controller. Oh yeah I finally was able to run Nokogiri, I just had to restart my server.

Comment: I'll accept this as the answer since I like nokogiri. Just a summary, the problem is that I didn't restart my server that's why when I included some gems, I'm getting an error. Lesson learned. Thanks everybody.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want `strip_tags` from the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html#method-i-strip_tags)

```
<%= "\"#{strip_tags(@text)}\"" %>
```

Edit:

Uglier, but gets rid of the &nbsp, too.

```
<%= "\"#{strip_tags(@text.gsub("&nbsp;", "")}\"" %>
```

Comment: So close bro. The output is what I wanted except the &nbsp; remains. I liked this answer and I think I can work out something from here. I'll accept this as the answer if no one else can top this. cheers

Comment: You can use `HTMLEntities.new.decode(markup)` to convert HTML entities (such as `&nbsp`) into UTF-8 characters.

Comment: When I tried to use HTMLEntities.new.decode(markup) , I got an error `uninitialized constant FulfillmentController::HTMLEntities` on my controller.

Comment: That's because HTMLEntitites is a library.  You'll have to include the gem in your Gemfile if you want to use it.  And it doesn't seem to be a well maintained gem, so it may or may not be useful to you.

Comment: when I try to add HTMLEntities (require 'HTMLEntities'), this error now comes up... `cannot load such file -- nokogiri` . It would be so helpful If we can make this work coz this will open up a whole bunch of library for me.

Comment: Nokogiri rules. It's a Ruby wrapper on libxml2, following _why's Hpricot programmer interface. I use it for tests that interrogate HTML with XPath.

Answer (score 0):

Try `.strip`:

```
<%= "\"#{@text.html_safe.strip}\"" %>
```

Comment: Sorry bro, didn't work. The output was the same as the second 1. All the tags are there.

Comment: `<%=raw "\"#{@text.html_safe.strip}\"" %>` is sending your HTML tags through as HTML tags. The strip is taking linefeeds off the ends of the payload. I lost track if you want the HTML tags gone, but can you try `.strip.html_safe`?

Comment: Nope, still the same output.